# Laravel how to return JSON when not in controller?

Tags: php, json, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

Is there some way to return JSON from laravel by using something similar to `abort()` function.

From controller returning JSON is easy we can just call

`return response()->json(['message' => 'my mesage'], 200);`

But from some other place (custom class for  example) to return JSON I have to create a return chain to the contoller.

Is there a way to return json without resorting to a return chain.
Like using `abort()` function.
I would like to use something similar to `abort(400, 'my message')` but insted of returning html like abort does return JSON.

or is there a way to overwrite `abort` to return JSON.

I would be thankfull solution that works for laravel 5.3 and up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all if you find yourself wondering such things you need to review your code.

The controller should get data which the controller is responsible for generating the appropriate response for. You shouldn't delegate response making to just about everywhere

You also should avoid `abort` outside controllers, you should throw proper exceptions.

That being said here's a fat ugly hack for you:

Create an exception:

```
class JsonResponse  extends Exception { 
     private $data;

     public __construct($data, $message = null, $code = 0, $previous = null) {
            $this->data = $data;
            parent::__construct($message,$code,$previous);
     }
}
```

In your Exception handler : usually `App\Exceptions\Handler`

```
 protected $dontReport = [
         // other lines
         JsonResponse::class  //
 ];

 public function render($request, Exception $exception) {
         if ($exception instanceof JsonResponse) {
              return reponse()->json($e->getData());
         }
         //Other lines
 }
```

Then whenever you need to immediately return a JSON response just do:

```
 throw new JsonResponse($data);
```

However this obviously fails within try-catch blocks.

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what i was looking for. I do understand that this method is a hack if used to return data. I was looking for a way to return JSON error messages when `Accept: application/json` is not in request header